# Using inpolyhedron Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the function inpolyhedron shown here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37856-inpolyhedron-are-points-inside-a-triangulated-volume-

However, I am having trouble creating the polyhedron the way the function wants it defined (a structure with fields 'vertices' and 'faces'). The raw data I have is a matrix of points x y z that are inside the polyhedron. So far, I have been using boundary() and trisurf() to plot the polyhedron.

Answer (score 0):

Dependant on what kind of polyhedron you want, you can use [`alphashape`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html), delaunay triangulation or `convhull`. So for example:

```
shp=alphaShape(x,y,z);
h=plot(shp);
```

You can access faces and vertices then like:

```
h.Vertices
h.Faces
```

It works the same way for `trisurf`:

```
tri=delaunay(x,y,z)
t=trisurf(tri,x,y,z)
```

To see which information is stored, you can use `get(t)`.
For faces and vertices it is the same thing as before:

```
t.Vertices
t.Faces
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'matlab.graphics.primitive.Patch'.

Comment: you have to edit your question with your code, and some example data, otherwise its hard to help you.